# Countability of certain subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $(0,1)$. Suppose every finite subset $\{x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n\}$ of $S$ with no two of $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ equal satisfies $x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2<1$. prove that $S$ is a countable set.

I have no idea how to begin. I know that countable union of countable sets is countable and I think it would be useful, thank you so much.

Comment: Suppose $S$ is uncountable. Pick a non-constant sequence of points in $S$ such that $x_n \not\to 0$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \infty$, so a subsequence must be $\ge 1$ at some point. That non-constant sequence ist given by $|S|>\aleph_0$.

Comment: Prove that in every set $(1/n, 1)$ there are only finitely many elements of $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Denote $I_{n}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},1)$ for all $n$. Note that if we have infinitely many $x_{k}\in S\cap I_{n}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, then 
\begin{align*}
1>x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{k}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_{i}^{2}\geq \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

And $(0,1)$ is a countable union of the sets $I_{n}$.